# What does mean this code 'true <=> false'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I saw this code `true <=> false` today.
But I dont know this expression and I can't understand this code how work.

Please help me to understand this code.

By the way, this code was written like this in control page animation of ionic 4.

```
export const FeedOut = trigger('state', [
  state('false', hiddenStyle),
  state('true', showStyle),
  transition('true <=> false', animate('300ms ease-in')),
  transition(':leave', animate(400, hiddenStyle)),
]);
```

Thank you

Comment: that is no expression, but a string. `<=>` looks like the spaceship operator, which is not implemented in JS.

Comment: Check this out: https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers

Comment: Thank you Comment.

I could understand : D.

Answer (score 1):

This code defines [transition animations in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-trigger). It defines a trigger called `'state'` which defines two states; called `'false'` and `'true'`.  <s>This has nothing to do with the actual javascript boolean values `false` and `true`, it's just how whoever wrote this code decided to call them. In fact, you could just change to something more descriptive, like `'hiddenState'` and `'shownState'`.</s>

Then it defines the transitions between the states, telling angular that the transition applies to both ways, either when going from `'false'` to `'true'`
 or from `'true'` to `'false'`.

Then you probably have some html code that says `[@state]="..."`. <s>If this contains the strings `'false'` and/or `'true'`, and you've decided to change the name of the states as I described above, you'll have to change it here too.</s>  I'd also recommend changing the word `'state'` to `'mytrigger'` to not get confused. This would also need to be changed both in the .ts file and the .html file(s)

**Edit: Actually, Angular seems to parse booleans for this nowadays, so you can simply use the state names  'true' and 'false', and then let Angular evaluate the truthiness inside the html without converting to a string**

Comment: since a couple versions ago, `true` and `false` in transitions can actually refer to transition states `true` and `false`. So booleans, and not just strings